# ¿Cómo opero aritméticamente los valores que se almacenan dentro de la lista del siguiente código?

Tags: python, lista, math

Un colaborador del foro me explicó la implementación y optimización para evitar la redundancia al evitar escribir tres líneas de código que vendrían siendo lo mismo.
Se declararon tres variables dentro de una tupla para que al ingresar los valores numéricos se almacenaran dentro de la lista. Lo que quiero saber es cómo puedo operarlos aritméticamente (ya sea sumándolos, restándoslos, multiplicándolos, etc.).

```
dimensiones = {'Columna': [], 'Trabe': [], 'Losa': []}
datos = ['altura', 'longitud', 'profundidad']

for tipo in dimensiones:
    for dato in datos:
        dimensiones[tipo].append(float(input(f'Ingrese la {dato} de su {tipo}: ')))

print(dimensiones)
```

Agradecería bastante su apoyo. Muchas gracias por su tiempo. Saludos!

Comment: Lo haces con `dimensiones[tipo]` ejemplo `print(dimensiones['Columna'])`, como esto contiene una lista solo accede a la posición de la lista para 9btener el número, ejemplo `print(dimensiones['Columna'][0])`

Comment: ¿No hay una forma más óptima de evitar esto?: `dimensiones['Columna'][0]+dimensiones['Columna'][1]+dimensiones['Columna'][2]`

Comment: Listo ya edite mi respuesta

Comment: Tu función para multiplicar que se me sugirió sugirió la edición estaba bien, sin embargo yo no lo rechazo fue @Comunidad, además con el código que te dejé es mucho más fácil, rápido y eficiente, pero estuvo bien tu punto de vista

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para acceder a un diccionario deberás poner la clave de esta forma
`dimensiones['Columna']` esto te devolverá el array que tiene el diccionario en la clave Columna.
Para acceder a un elemento de este array solo deberás especificar la posición del elemento, ejemolo `print(dimensiones['Columna'][0])`

**Ejercicio práctico**

```
dimensiones = {'Columna': [2 3], 'Trabe': [3,4], 'Losa': [1,1]}
Columna = dimensiones['Columna'][0] #=2
Trabe = dimensiones['Trabe'][0] #=3
Losa = dimensiones['Losa'][0] #=1
```

Teniendo estos datos ya podrás operar, esto lo puedes hacer más dinámico con ayuda de un ciclo for, de la misma forma que agregas los datos en tu código, así podrás leerlos

**Operando**

Por el comentario que me dijiste, hay una forma más óptima de sumar todos los datos del arreglo, con la funcion `sum()`, solo obtenemos los valores de cada clave del diccionario

```
for d in dimensiones:
     print(sum(dimensiones[d]))
```

Si se quiere realizar otra operación cada valor por separado, se deberá acceder a cada elemto del arreglo de tal forma.

```
for d in dimensiones:
     for v in range(len(dimensiones[d])):
         #operamos con los valores de columna y trabe
          op = dimensiones['Columna'][v]* dimensiones['Trabe'][v]
          print(op)
```

`v` vendría ser el valor de cada elemento del arreglo y todos deben de tener la misma longitud, de lo contrario esto indicaría que falta un dato.
Si quieres realizar la operación de multiplicación lo puedes hacer con ayuda de una librería `functools`  y con expresiones *lambda*.

```
from functools import reduce
for d in dimensiones:
     reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, dimensiones[d])
```

Lo mismo para la división, solo cambias el operador, esto es para python3, si usas otra versión puedes investigar

Comment: Una pregunta más, si solo quiero multiplicar o dividir solo los elementos por todos los números que contenga, cómo lo hago?

Comment: Lo siento no te entiendo muy bien, podrías dar un ejemplo?

Comment: Por ejemplo, si solo quiero multiplicar esto: 
Ingrese la altura de su Losa: 5
Ingrese la longitud de su Losa: 4
Ingrese la profundidad de su Losa: 3
[5.0, 4.0, 3.0] y me arroje 60

Comment: Tu código funciona de maravilla, pero mi inquietud es solo multiplicar una sola fila por los números que contenga

Comment: Se me ocurre esto: 
def multiply(numbers):  
    total = 1
    for x in numbers:
        total *= x  
    return total  
print(multiply((dimensiones[tipo])))

Comment: De hecho, ya lo resolví xd, gracias

Comment: Jaja, bueno, igual ya edite la respuesta, lo siento lo esta probando en el Google Colab 